# Different sort order with Array#sort() and Object.entries().sort()

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have two data structures holding the same data that need to be sorted the same way: one is an array of strings, and the other a plain object with the same strings as properties.

Example:

```
"Ciencias Da Saude Gerontologia"
"Ciencias Da Saude Educação Especial"
"Ciencias Da Saude"
```

Depending on whether these are elements of an array, or are properties of a plain object, I get different results when I sort them. See the different output orders in this snippet:

```js
const allUniques = [
    "Ciencias Da Saude Gerontologia",
    "Ciencias Da Saude Educação Especial",
    "Ciencias Da Saude"
];
const allUniquesSorted = Array.from(allUniques).sort();
console.log(allUniquesSorted); // "Ciencias Da Saude" is first

const propertiesNotSorted =  {
   "Ciencias Da Saude Gerontologia": "",
   "Ciencias Da Saude Educação Especial": "",
   "Ciencias Da Saude": ""
};
const propertiesSorted = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(propertiesNotSorted).sort()
);
console.log(propertiesSorted); // "Ciencias Da Saude" is last
```

As you can see "Ciencias Da Saude" gets output first in the array version, but last in the object properties version.

What could I do so *both* the array and object properties get the same ordering? Like this:

1. Preferred

   ```
   [
      "Ciencias Da Saude",
      "Ciencias Da Saude Educação Especial", 
      "Ciencias Da Saude Gerontologia"
   ]
   {
      "Ciencias Da Saude": "",
      "Ciencias Da Saude Educação Especial": "",
      "Ciencias Da Saude Gerontologia": ""
   }
   ```

Or:

2. Acceptable alternative

   ```
   [
      "Ciencias Da Saude Educação Especial",
      "Ciencias Da Saude Gerontologia", 
      "Ciencias Da Saude"
   ]
   {
      "Ciencias Da Saude Educação Especial": "",
      "Ciencias Da Saude Gerontologia": "",
      "Ciencias Da Saude": ""
   }
   ```

Comment: `Object.entries` returns key-value pairs. `.sort()` will by default take the string representation of the two values passed in and do a lexicographical sort. Doing `String(["key", "value"])` is quite different from just `"value"`

Comment: Also, it's usually not a good idea to rely on the order of object's keys. Yes, it *is* guranteed nowadays but it's also very easy to disturb it by accident. There is legacy code that still exists that doesn't respect the order of object properties. Big offenders are serialisation/deserialisation libraries. If you pass your object through the network, you might get it with a different order of the keys to what you'd expect.

Comment: Why are you calling `Array.from()` when it's already an array?

Comment: I don't get your result when I sort `allUniques`. I get `Ciencias Da Saude` first, just like in the object.

Comment: The outputs in the question seem to be reversed: the short string gets sorted *first* in the *array* version, and gets sorted *last* in the object version. I suppose the OP made a mistake in their post.

Comment: Thank you all for your knowledge. Indeed, my bad, i reversed the outputs, will update :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't rely on any order for plain objects. Although the language now guarantees a certain order, this is not the case in older versions of the language. Plain objects were never intended to be *ordered* collections, and you can get unexpected results when number-like properties are used (because the rules for ordering are specific for a certain range of numbers). In short, it is not considered best practice to rely on an order.

If you need order, use arrays.

Having said that, you can get your desired result as follows:

```js
let propertiesNotSorted =  {
   "Ciencias Da Saude Gerontologia": "",
   "Ciencias Da Saude Educação Especial": "",
   "Ciencias Da Saude": ""
}
  
let propertiesSorted = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(propertiesNotSorted).sort(([a],[b]) =>
        a.localeCompare(b)
    )
);

console.log(propertiesSorted);
```

...but again, the results will be unexpected if you have properties that are numbers or number-like in your input. Look at how odd this order is:

```js
let propertiesNotSorted =  {
   "Ciencias Da Saude Gerontologia": "",
   "Ciencias Da Saude Educação Especial": "",
   "999999999": "",
   "0.0000001": "",
   "1.0000001": "",
   "4444444444": "",
   "099999999": "",
   "3333333333": "",
   "Ciencias Da Saude": ""
}
  
let propertiesSorted = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(propertiesNotSorted).sort(([a],[b]) =>
        a.localeCompare(b)
    )
);

console.log(propertiesSorted);
```

... and there is no way to avoid that *some* number-like properties always precede other properties in a plain object iteration. **Use arrays when order matters**.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you very much for your answer and knowledge. This is exactly what i needed for now, now i am aware of the problems, but i do believe that atm there isn't much of a option for me. Senior guy wants it to be done that way, hopefully i can change his mind with yours and @VLAZ answers.